# Get frequency of values for multiple columns using dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, frequency

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
 a    b    c    d      e
 1    0    0    1      1
.5    1    1    0      1
 1    1.  .5   .5.     0
 0    0    1    NA     1
 0    1    0    1     .5
```

I am looking for an output like:

```
 col    val      count
  a      1        2
        .5        1
         0        2
  b      1        3
         0        2
  c      1        2
        .5        1
         0        2
  d      1        2
        .5        1
         0        1
        NA        1
  e      1        3
        .5        1
         0        1
```

I have tried using

```
data %>% 
  summarize_at(colnames(data)), n(), na.rm = TRUE)
```

but this doesn't give me what I want. Any suggestions greatly appreciated,  thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've assumed column d row 3 is a typo and .5. really is 0.5, in which case you could do the following:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
  group_by(name, value) %>% 
  summarise(count = n()) %>% 
  arrange(name, desc(value))

# or more succinctly as pointed out by @LMc

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
  count(name, value) %>% 
  arrange(name, desc(value))

#> # A tibble: 15 x 3
#>    name  value count
#>    <chr> <dbl> <int>
#>  1 a       1       2
#>  2 a       0.5     1
#>  3 a       0       2
#>  4 b       1       3
#>  5 b       0       2
#>  6 c       1       2
#>  7 c       0.5     1
#>  8 c       0       2
#>  9 d       1       2
#> 10 d       0.5     1
#> 11 d       0       1
#> 12 d      NA       1
#> 13 e       1       3
#> 14 e       0.5     1
#> 15 e       0       1
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(a = c(1, 0.5, 1, 0, 0), b = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1), 
                     c = c(0, 1, 0.5, 1, 0), d = c(1, 0, 0.5, NA, 1), 
                     e = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0.5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                  -5L))
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: You can simplify this more by replacing the `group_by` and `summarise` pipes with just `count(name, value)`.